# C# udp socket not receiving entire message

Tags: c#

I have the following method which sends an rcon command to a game server.

```
public string sendCommand(string command)
{
byte[] bufferTemp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
byte[] bufferSend = new byte[bufferTemp.Length + 4];

//big enough to receive response
byte[] bufferRec = new byte[65000];

//intial 4 characters as per standard
bufferSend[0] = byte.Parse("255");
bufferSend[1] = byte.Parse("255");
bufferSend[2] = byte.Parse("255");
bufferSend[3] = byte.Parse("255");
int j = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < bufferTemp.Length; i++)
{
    bufferSend[j++] = bufferTemp[i];
}

//send rcon command and get response
try
{
    this.server.Socket.Send(bufferSend, SocketFlags.None);
    this.server.Socket.Receive(bufferRec);
}
catch (SocketException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error occured");
}

string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferRec);

return response;
}
```

out of all the commands I can possibly send, 1 of them returns a lot more data than the others and it seems that the *buffer_rec* byte array only gets about 1/4 of the message, but that array has been declared big enough to contain all the data.
On the subsequent 3 requests, the rest of the data gets output, as if it was buffered in some way.

I don't know why this is taking place. If you do, could you please let me know how to remedy the problem?

Thank you
Crouz

Comment: `The Receive method reads data into the buffer parameter and **returns the number of bytes successfully read**` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx

Comment: I know that it does, but there is no way for me to know how many bytes should be returned in total by the server, so I don't know when i have finished reading data I'm afraid.

Comment: @user1834208: Even aside from that, you should *always* use the return value. At the moment you're creating a string from the *whole* of `bufferRec`, regardless of how much data was read. Don't do that. Next, you should use something like Wireshark to see what's *actually* happening on the network.

Comment: Ok, what should I do instead? How do I get all of the data from the server?

Comment: UDP will divide your "message" into multiple packets if the message is larger than some defined "max UDP packet size" OS setting. So when you `Receive`, you're possibly receiving only one of those packets. You need to keep reading until you reach the end of the message. Apparently, you have a messaging protocol, so I bet that protocol defines some way of knowing the end of the message.

Comment: Also note that UPD does not guarantee message integrity so, you need to handle the cases where packets are _dropped_ (lost) or they come in a different order than they were sent.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this and see if there is an end of message character.

Comment: Ok, I have looked into this on the web as well as using wireshark to identify any potential end of message marker, to no avail. There has to be a way around this, but I don't know much about socket and I am a bit lost to be honest. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Crouzilles how do you not know the size of the message? Most protocols will include a size of the message in their application header

Comment: @L.B + Eren, UDP will NOT split up or give you a partial message.  It's a datagram protocol, not a stream one.  You will either get the whole thing or nothing at all.

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone, when using wireshark, I see 5 distinct packets received as a response for a "cvarlist" request. It is those 5 packets I am reading one by one into the buffer. I am afraid, I don't get the whole thing in 1 go nor do I get nothing at all.

Comment: @Brad Semrad, I cannot see anything using wireshark to indicate how long the received message should be.

Comment: Crouzilles - then they are being sent as 5 distinct packets. UDP is a datagram protocol, not a stream one.  It will NOT mess with your packets

Comment: @Kieren, thanks for clearing this out.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, it seems that after 6 hours of looking into this I have finally come up with a solution, so here is a small change made to the receiving of data, note the thread sleeping for 10ms, this seems to be needed to let the datagrams arrive in due time.

```
    //send rcon command and get response
    string response = "";
    try
    {
        this.server.Socket.Send(bufferSend, SocketFlags.None);

        do
        {
            int bytesReceived = this.server.Socket.Receive(bufferRec);
            response += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferRec, 0, bytesReceived);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        } while (this.server.Socket.Available > 0);
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error occured");
    }
```

If you think there is a better or more elegant way of handling this, don't hesitate to slam my code, but do so by offering an alternative as I am always happy to learn new things. Regards, Crouz

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. This works by chance. You really need to re-work your protocol to contain a header that signals the message length, and read until you have that number of bytes, or define some kind of "message end" delimiter, so that your message parsing code knows when it has a message. Also, note that you currently have zero protection against packet corruption (you need to implement some kind of checksum for this) or reordering (if you care, you need to implement some kind of sequence number). Or just use TCP and you get a lot of the above for free.

Comment: The key remains "The Receive method reads data into the buffer parameter and **returns the number of bytes successfully read**". Your loop for receiving bytes should simply append those bytes into a buffer. Then, **separately**, you should examine that buffer to see if you have one or more complete messages to process. ("Complete message" is as per your protocol design.) When you do have a message, remove **just those bytes** from the buffer, do whatever processing you need to do (fire an event, whatever), then start the cycle again.

Comment: I haven't designed the quake3 protocol, so I cannot make changes to it to let me know how long a message will be I'm afraid. I have no control over the server side basically. I have used wireshark to examine the packet, nowhere can I see a message length nor a end of message marker (mind you, I am very new to wireshark, I could be missing something).

Comment: http://www.gamers.org/dEngine/quake/QDP/qnp.html#header - check byte 3 and 4 of the packet. Though I'm on a smartphone and not 100% sure the protocol doc applies to Quake 3.